# What query will return consumption per hour from SQLite data with cumulative value?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Firstly, I am almost a complete novice when it comes to SQL, so I am painfully aware I probably need to be spoon-fed anything but the simplest queries. I have been searching a lot, but most relevant examples I find seem to be too complex or general to help me with my problem.

I have the following table in a SQLite database:

| CHANGE_DATE | NEW_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-20 01:21:53 | 341 |
| 2022-01-20 01:11:55 | 341 |
| 2022-01-19 23:05:16 | 341 |
| 2022-01-19 22:55:08 | 340 |
| 2022-01-19 22:45:08 | 340 |
| 2022-01-19 22:41:02 | 340 |
| 2022-01-19 20:38:46 | 339 |
| 2022-01-19 20:35:13 | 339 |
| 2022-01-19 20:25:15 | 339 |
| 2022-01-19 20:15:08 | 338 |
| 2022-01-19 18:11:42 | 338 |
| 2022-01-19 18:05:10 | 338 |

What I would like to do is have a query that returns the total change per hour. Mathematically I can subtract the highest value from each hour from the highest value from previous hour or calculate the difference between highest/lowest value within each hour (and also per day in my next step).

I have tried to understand and modify a lot of examples with somewhat similar requirements, but at this point I do not know where to start. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: About ORM: Actually, i have near to no programming language skills, so im after a pure SQLite query that i can paste into my Grafana dashboard, or make a SQLite view from.

Comment: To simplify: Consider the above table: How can i make a pure SQL query that show the highest value of NEW_VALUE each hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use some ORMs which is related to your language skill

javascript : mock
c# : dapper , entity framework
python : sqlallschemi
java : spring
...

---

So if you want pure SQL query i hope below code help you :

this code show you the max of new_value of each hour to you :

```
select Max(new_value) as max_value , strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', 
change_date) as _date
from [table_name] 
GROUP BY strftime('%H', change_date),strftime('%j', change_date)
ORDER by _date DESC
```

and this code will show you the total change per hour between different values in an hour:

```
select Max(new_value)-Min(new_value) as total_change_per_hour , strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', change_date) as _date
from [table_name] 
GROUP BY strftime('%H', change_date),strftime('%j', change_date)
ORDER by _date DESC
```

if you want it per day just change it to this code :

```
select Max(new_value)-Min(new_value) as total_change_per_hour , strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', change_date) as _date
from [table_name] 
GROUP BY strftime('%j', change_date)
ORDER by _date DESC
```

you should replace [table_name] with your table name

you can learn more about working with times in sql by [this link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Awesome. This query is just what i was after, and also they are so simple compared to the examples i have been trying to understand that i think i can iterate on them. Thank you very much. - The two last queries does not work 100% for me though, because this sensor sometimes records a value of 0.1 for some reason - is there a simpke way of excluding those values? - Also, my next step will be to try to multiply the value of say the middle query (difference within each hour) with another value from the same table, but from the same query  (with a different WHERE clause) - any pointer for that?